# How to get the actual width of the vbox in TeX

Tags: pdftex, tex-core

I'm trying to obtain in TeX the actual size of the box after inserting material which is overflowing the size of the box.

I can easily get the hight by reading \ht0 and \dp0, but when I read \wd0 I'm getting the size of the vbox but not the size of the actual material put inside the box.

[image]

In the example above, the width is set for 350pt. And this is what I get by reading \wd0.  But the actual text size in that box is way wider.

Any idea?

---

Remarks:

It is the whole story why I'm looking for that?

This is the code (based on some other solution found in this group, but not working well). The problem is how to automatically adjust the font size to make the text fitting closely to the box defined under certain limits. It was discussed in this group many times, but none of the described solutions works fine for my cases. The code works but not if the text is very short. Mainly it doesn't work because the only factor which is checked is if the text is not longer than the box depth by reading \ht0 and \dp0 dimensions. But it should be another aspect taken into account - f the text is not wider than the box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{environ}% http://ctan.org/pkg/environ
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{lato}
\newdimen\fontdim
\newdimen\upperfontdim
\newdimen\lowerfontdim
\newif\ifmoreiterations
\fontdim12pt

\makeatletter%
\NewEnviron{fitbox}[2]{% \begin{fitbox}{<width>}{<height>} stuff \end{fitbox}
  \def\buildbox{%
    \setbox0\vbox{\hbox{\minipage{#1}%
      \fontsize{\fontdim}{1.2\fontdim}%
      \selectfont%
      \stuff%
    \endminipage}}%
    \dimen@\ht0%
    \advance\dimen@\dp0%
  }%
  \def\stuff{\BODY}% Store environment body
  \buildbox%
  % Compute upper and lower bounds
  \ifdim\dimen@>#2%
    \loop%
      \fontdim.5\fontdim% Reduce font size by half
      \message{Reducing fontsize}%
      \buildbox%
    \ifdim\dimen@>#2 \repeat%
    \lowerfontdim\fontdim%
    \upperfontdim2\fontdim%
    \fontdim1.5\fontdim%
  \else%
    \loop%
      \fontdim2\fontdim% Double font size
      \message{Doubling fontsize \the\fontdim\space Par2: #2}%
      \buildbox %
      \ifdim\dimen1 > \dimen3%
        % \message{Width lower then max}%
      \else%
        \message{Width biggern then max}%
      \fi%
    \ifdim\dimen@<#2 \repeat%
    \upperfontdim\fontdim%
    \lowerfontdim.5\fontdim%
    \fontdim.75\fontdim%
  \fi%
  % Now try to find the optimum size
  \loop%
    \message{Bounds: \the\lowerfontdim\space \the\fontdim\space \the\upperfontdim^^J}%
    \buildbox%
    \ifdim\dimen@>#2 %
      \moreiterationstrue%
      \upperfontdim\fontdim%
      \advance\fontdim\lowerfontdim%
      \fontdim.5\fontdim%
    \else%
      \advance\dimen@-#2%
      \ifdim\dimen@<10pt%
        \lowerfontdim\fontdim%
        \advance\fontdim\upperfontdim%
        \fontdim.5\fontdim%
        \dimen@\upperfontdim%
        \advance\dimen@-\lowerfontdim%
        \ifdim\dimen@<.2pt%
          \moreiterationsfalse%
        \else%
          \moreiterationstrue%
        \fi%
      \else%
        \moreiterationsfalse%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  \ifmoreiterations \repeat%
  \box0% Typeset content
}
\makeatother%
\begin{document}
\fbox{%
\begin{fitbox}{87mm}{35mm}%
  \lato\fontseries{eb}\selectfont \nohyphens{COMEDIANS WINS}
\end{fitbox}%
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How do you produce that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @egreg I extended the problem description

Comment: @dexteritas  I extended the problem description

Comment: I think a better solution would be to measure the natural width of the text, calculate the ratio between this width and the desired box width and put the text in a scalebox that is scaled down by that very ratio.

Comment: If you want to determine the maximum word width, you can use xstring to parse words (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501221/how-to-split-a-string-variable-into-an-array-and-call-from-an-array/501355?r=SearchResults&s=1|0.0000#501355).

Comment: There is also the varwidth package, but it requires a maximum width for wrapping text.